# How to acces a one to many relation without depending on the nested model entity framework .net 6

Tags: entity-framework, .net-6.0

I have a .net 6 project with entity framework and the following models:

```
public class Company
    {
        [Key]
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(50)]
        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(50)]
        public string? Description { get; set; }
    }
```

```
    public class Device
    {
        [Key]
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [MaxLength(15)]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(30)]
        public string Description { get; set; }

        public virtual Company Company { get; set; }
    }
```

I want `Company` to have a one to many relationship with `Device`. But I dont want that `Company` is dependend on `Device` so i can't add `public virtual ICollection<Device> Devices { get; set; }` to the company class.

Is there a way to create a one to many connection between these two classes but dont let Company depend on device and still do things like this: `_context.Companies.Include(x => x.Devices);`?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can achieve a one-to-many relationship between Company and Device without making Company dependent on Device by using the Fluent API in Entity Framework.

To configure the relationship using Fluent API, you can add the following code to the OnModelCreating method in your DbContext class:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Device>()
        .HasOne(d => d.Company)
        .WithMany()
        .HasForeignKey(d => d.CompanyId);

    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

In this code, we're configuring a one-to-many relationship between Device and Company. The HasOne method specifies that each Device has one Company, and the WithMany method specifies that each Company has many Devices. We're not specifying any navigation property for the Company side, so the relationship will be unidirectional from Device to Company. Finally, the HasForeignKey method specifies the foreign key property to be used to store the relationship between Device and Company.

With this configuration, you can still use _context.Companies.Include(x => x.Devices) to eagerly load Devices for a Company. However, you will need to manually include the Company when querying for Devices. For example:

```
var devices = _context.Devices.Include(d => d.Company).ToList();
```

This will load all Devices from the database, including their associated Company objects.